# Passing const char * to file.open(), strange behavior

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm having problem with the code below. I'm experiencing different behaviors depending on what IDE I'm using.

**Dev-C++:** Runs fine. However, if I pass `GenerateFileName(0,0)` to `file.open()`, no file is created.

**Visual Studio 2013:** Runs fine in all cases, however, the name of the file generated looks like

```
ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌPùD
```

or something like that, and the file itself has no extension (I expect a `.txt` file ).

```
int main()
{
    ofstream file;
    file.open(GenerateFileName(3, 0));
    file << 1 << endl;
    file.close();
    _getch();
}

const char* GenerateFileName(int Instance_nth, int Input_nth)
{
    string filename = to_string(Instance_nth);
    filename += "_";
    filename += to_string(Input_nth);
    filename += ".txt";

    return filename.c_str();
}
```

Comment: In `GenerateFileName()` the variable `filename` is destroyed when the function returns, so the function's return value is a garbage.

Comment: You are returning a pointer to a local variable. That's UB.

Comment: Just return the string from the function

Comment: Change the return type of  `GenerateFileName` to `std::string`

Comment: BTW: Any reasonable compiler should warn you about this.

Comment: In C++11 `ofstream::open` [can handle](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/open/) `std::string` as well as `const char *`.

Comment: `Ì`'s codepoint is 0xCC which is [uninitialized memory in MSVC debug mode](http://stackoverflow.com/q/370195/995714)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
const char* GenerateFileName(int Instance_nth, int Input_nth)
{
    string filename = to_string(Instance_nth);
    filename += "_";
    filename += to_string(Input_nth);
    filename += ".txt";

    return filename.c_str();
}
```

You're returning a pointer to the data internally stored by `filename` while it is destroyed with `GenerateFileName`'s ending: the returned value is a dangling pointer, and your code is undefined behaviour.

What you can do is returning a `std::string` instead of `const char*`:

```
std::string GenerateFileName(int Instance_nth, int Input_nth)
{
    string filename = to_string(Instance_nth);
    filename += "_";
    filename += to_string(Input_nth);
    filename += ".txt";

    return filename;
}
```

Usage would become:

```
file.open(GenerateFileName(3, 0).c_str());
```

Comment: Thanks. But I'm still wondering why the code runs fine on Dev  C++ ( except the scenario when I pass GenerateFileName(0, 0) into file.open()) but not on Visual Studio.

Comment: Undefined behaviour = you can't expect it to run fine for sure, but you can't expect it to crash for sure either. Your code may run fine with some versions of some compilers -- looks like it's the case for the compiler behind your version of Dev C++, but you may have different behaviours with different compilers or even with different versions of the same compiler

Answer (score 1):

This is undefined behavior, because `filename` is destroyed, once you leave `GenenerateFileName` function, and `file.open` is receiving pointer, which is pointing to already destroyed variable data.

Easiest thing here is to return `std::string` from `GenerateFileName` and do something like `file.open(GenerateFileName(0,0).c_str());`